# How to declare a method that can be used only inside another method in a java interface?

Tags: java

How to declare a method that can be used only inside another method in a java interface?

```
public interface VendingMachine_ADT {

    public void selectDrink(Drink d);
    public void MoneyEntered(Coin c);
    public void DrinkSelectedandMoneyEntered();
    public void cancel();//i want this method inside selectDrink();

}
```

Comment: You can't. Interfaces are the public "shape" of a class; if you don't want another class to be able to call a `cancel()` method, don't put it in the interface.

Comment: Note that that `public` on the method declarations is redundant, all methods on an `interface` are necessarily `public`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you can, with come coercion, achieve this in C++ (which somewhat legitimises this question), you cannot do this in Java.

All methods in a Java `interface` are necessarily `public`. Really the concept of a `private` method localised to a particular function is more to do with the *implementation* of that interface rather than the interface itself.

So you'd need to enforce your restriction in an implementation of `selectDrink()`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that. All methods in an interface are meant to be public.

Apparently, you have several classes that implement `VendingMachine_ADT`, and they use a method named `cancel` that is the same for them - or at least similar.
In this case, you can make a base class for `VendingMachine_ADT`, and make `cancel` a protected method of the base class. Your `cancel` method will be available to descendant classes.

Depending on your needs, you could even have `cancel` as an abstract method, to be implemented by subclasses. That is as close to an interface as you can get.